# Multiple Custom Cells in a single UICollectionViewController, Cycled between with a NavigationBarButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, custom-cell

I had Previously created three different UICollectionView's and placed three different custom cells into each of them linking them together with a simple tab bar button. After some Help i have managed to narrow the code down to just one UICollectionViewController and now i simply just need to know how to toggle between each custom cell via a NavigationBarButton.

It would also be helpful if i could change the buttons icon dependant on what option of the button has been clicked (Three clicks will be needed as follows (ListView, SmallIconView, and LargeIconView)).

Any suggestions?

ViewController.h

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface GroupsViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
}

@end

@implementation GroupsViewController
{
    NSString *reuseIdentifier;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon";
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];


    arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ac-cars.png", nil];
    arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one", nil];

}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell IconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell IconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return SmallIcon; //error message (use of undeclared identifier)

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

CustomCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *IconImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *IconLabel;

@end
```

I have now connected all three Custom Cells in to one UICollectionView connections all the labels and images to the same outlets.
[image: Collection View With 3 Custom Cells]

As you can see i have now removed the three view controllers and placing all the custom Cells in to one UICollectionView. I have linked all the labels and images to the appropriate outlets.

How do i connect the tab bar button? and where do i implement the code for the button at? Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You only need one collectionView with three customCells in it.**

> Add three collectionViewCell For the landscape layout with a different
>   reuseIdentifier for each.Then on each button action,change the
>   reuseIdentifier and reload the collectionView.

***This is how you do it:***

Declare a NSString variable for reuseIdentifier of collectionViewCell like :

`NSString reuseIdentifier;`
in the implementation section.

Then in the `viewWillApper` set a default identifier for the cell which is the default one.

```
reuseIdentifier=@"largeIconVIewCellIdentifier";
```

Then in the button action of the navigation bar button,set the `reuseIdentifier` as required and reload the collectionview.The code will be like:

```
-(void)cellToggleAction
{
if([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"SmallIcon"])
reuseIdentifier=@"ListView";
}
else if ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"ListView"])
reuseIdentifier=@"LargeIcon";
}
else if ([reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"LargeIcon"])
reuseIdentifier=@"SmallIcon";
}
[collectionView reloadData];
}
```

Thats it!! You are all set.
The following is a sample image for your reference.

> These are three customCells with same class but different reuse
>   identifiers.

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
#import "GroupsViewController.h"
#import "CustomCell.h"

@interface GroupsViewController ()
{
    NSArray *arrayOfImages;
    NSArray *arrayOfDescriptions;
}

@end

@implementation GroupsViewController
{
        NSString *reuseIdentifier;

 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
      reuseIdentifier= @"SmallIcon";
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
    [[self GroupsCollectionView]setDelegate:self];


    arrayOfImages = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ac-cars.png", nil];
    arrayOfDescriptions = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"one", nil];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayOfDescriptions count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    CustomCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [[cell SmallIconImage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]]];
    [[cell SmallIconLabel]setText:[arrayOfDescriptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];

    return SmallIcon;


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    //Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

and in the CustomCell.h file:

```
        #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomCell : UICollectionViewCell

//Small Icon
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *SmallIconImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *SmallIconLabel;
@end
```

Also add the buttonAction that I have added above.

Comment: Try the code and let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: How would i embed the current code you have given in to my current code? i will post up the code now and thanks for your input, what your explaining and showing in the images is exactly what i want to do.

Comment: You did it the hard way.Just create an imageView outlet and a description Label outlet in the customCell.h and connect all the three cell's image and label to these two outlets.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but where do i put the button exactly? I'm kind of new to this, also when i implement the code you suggested i get an error from the return SmallIcon; Line saying it is undeclared. Any Suggestions?

Comment: You should return the cell.remove `return SmallIcon;` and add `return cell;` in `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
` method

Comment: For the `navigation bar button`, cntrl+drag the button to your `viewcontroller.h` file and create an action named `cellToggleAction`.And in the `viewcontroller.m` file,Inside the definition of `cellToggleAction` method, add the code to change the `reuseIdentifier` and reload the `collectionview`.Hope you got the logic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using an `enum` and holding a property for that `enum` type. Toggle the `enum` with the button, and in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath:` set three different sizes per condition based on the `enum`. When the size is toggled in the button, make sure to call `reloadData` after you've set the property.

If the cell needs to adjust its layout per height (beyond just a height increase), you could have the cell class own the `enum` and apply styling within for each intended height. Make sure it's public so the property in the VC can reference it and apply it to the cell within `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` along with `sizeForItemAtIndex:`.